# TFS Data Warehouse Problem extracting Test Run history - extra rows in FactTestResult table (PointID, ChangeNumber)

Tags: sql, tfs, azure-devops, warehouse

I am building a Power BI report to display Test Executions for Azure DevOps (On-Prem). This data is not exposed via OData so I have to use a live connection to the TFS Analysis instance. Due to the live connection in Power BI, I am not able to add to the Data Model as I would like. I have written some queries to retrieve the data from the Data Warehouse I need but I have noticed that there are a number of extra rows in the FactTestResult table that contain values for the **PointId and ChangeNumber - not really sure what these records are used for as I can not see them in the UI - Azure DevOps Server 2020**. Adding the filter ResultCount = 1 will remove these other rows resulting in a single row. There is however only a single row remaining where **AreaSK and IterationSK are both null** - unlike the columns I have just filtered out. Ideally I would be able to join on the Area and Iteration and I can work around this problem, I would just like to understand what is the purpose of these extra rows - PointID and ChangeNumber and is there a better way to write the Test execution history query below.

```
SELECT *
  FROM [Tfs_Warehouse].[dbo].[vFactTestResultOverlay] FTRO
  join vDimTestRunOverlay DTRO on 
  DTRO.TestRunSK = FTRO.TestRunSK 
  where DTRO.TestRunId = "testRunID" and 
  TeamProjectCollectionSK = "projectCollectionID"
```

[image]

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

> TFS Data Warehouse Problem extracting Test Run history - extra rows in FactTestResult table (PointID, ChangeNumber)

For the `PointID`, we could to know it is the ID of test point. Indeed, we cannot see it directly on the UI, but we could get it by the REST API:

[Points - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/points/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Plans/{planId}/Suites/{suiteId}/points?api-version=6.0
```

[image]

And we could see Points on the UI:

[image]

For the `ChangeNumber`, I also could not get much info about it, just the document about it:

[Test Results and Test Runs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/sql-reports/test-result-tables?view=azure-devops-2020#test-results-and-test-runs)

Comment: REST api or OData queries are good for use with Power BI. My preferred method however was using SSRS for paginated reports which meant the Tfs_Warehouse was a slightly better option in my case. Also I wanted to get a summary over all projects and test plans in one query. Much obliged for your input.

Answer (score 0):

using code similar to the following I managed to order and find the most recent record without the null entries for iteration and area. Didn't explicitly refer to changeNumber in the end.

```
select 
*, 
Row_Number() over (partition by FTR.TeamProjectSK,FTR.TestSuiteSK,FTR.TestCaseId,FTR.ConfigurationSK order by FTR.ResultDate desc) as TestResultsPerTestCaseOrderedDesc
from [Tfs_Warehouse].[dbo].[FactTestResult] FTR 
where PointrecordCount = 1
```